# reload fancybox without reloading the page

Tags: fancybox

I have 1st FB popup showing a small image and some data. I want to be able to click on the image and load/reload bigger version of the same image, with back button to go back to first FB popup ... im a simple programmer and need simple solution pls

Comment: Could you please elaborate and show use what you already have so we can get a better understanding of what you're trying to do? Also, which version of fancybox do you use and what options do you initialize it with?